# HTTP load failed with status 403. Load of media resource

Tags: html, centos7, http-status-code-403, centos-web-panel

my friends have problems with centos webpanel, i use php native, when i add audio on the web an error appears : HTTP load failed with status 403. Load of media resource

my code :

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src='sound.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
</audio>
```

Comment: None of this appears to be related to PHP. It's just HTML and an MP3 file. I've updated the tags to something which seems more relevant. 403 means "Forbidden" so please check that your webserver's user account has permission to access that file

Comment: That's html not php. Also try to show all the code related.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried changing the permissions but it didn't work, I see the mistake is not wanting to read the scrib "resource" is there any possible solution

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue I faced and solved by disabling Mod Security.

- Go to the CentOS web panel
- On the dashboard CWP setting, there is a Mod Security option
- Turn OFF the mod security or edit rules (if you need to ON mod security)